# Convertir imagen en caracteres

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

estoy haciendo un aplicativo que me permite reconocer monedas pero estoy detenido en esta parte, he buscado como volver una imagen a string o carácter o por lo menos reconocer los caracteres pero no encuentro nada entendible, ojala puedan ayudarme o darme ideas de como hacerlo.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

kernel = 5

img = cv2.imread("D:\Backup_Sony\DISCO D\Software Development\VI Semestre\Electiva II\Open_cv\Images\IMG5.jpg")
gris = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imshow("gris", gris)

# SUAVIZADO PROMEDIO
media = cv2.medianBlur(img, 7)

suavizada = cv2.GaussianBlur(gris, (kernel, kernel), 0)
cv2.imshow("suavizada", suavizada)

umblar = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(suavizada, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 7, 3)
cv2.imshow("Umbralmedia", umblar)

umblarg = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(suavizada, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 7, 5)
cv2.imshow("Umbralg", umblarg)


# METODO CANNY
canny = cv2.Canny(suavizada, 40, 250)
#cv2.imshow("Canny", canny)
(contornos, _) = cv2.findContours(canny.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Cantidad de monedas
print("Se han encontrado {} monedas".format(len(contornos)))

cv2.drawContours(img,contornos, -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
cv2.imshow("Original", img)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

No se que librería usar para esta parte del código.

Comment: Edward, cuando dices que quieres "volver una imagen a string", imagino que quieres extraer los caracteres de la moneda, su valor, fecha en que fue acuñada, etc. Te sugiero investigar el módulo **pytesseract**.

Comment: Solo necesito el valor, pero apenas vi tu respuesta, ya mismo mira ese modulo a ver, gracias...

Comment: Me parece que lo que buscas más bien es detección de patrones no OCR. En opencv eso se llama template matching, revisa este documento: https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d4/dc6/tutorial_py_template_matching.html

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV convierte las imagenes a numpy arrays. Si quieres ver los valores de los pixeles de la imagen resultante del metodo canny solo tienes que ver el output de "canny". No estoy seguro tampoco de a que te refieres exactamente en volver una imagen a string. Si quieres convertir el numpy array de la imagen a string, podrias usar `flatten()` de OpenCV. Aqui un ejemplo de como hacerlo:

```
a = str(canny.flatten().tolist())
a.strip('[]').replace(',','')
```